# ExtJs4 - Infinite Scrolling - How to implement on the server side?

Tags: extjs4, infinite-scroll

I'm really stuck at this. I have set up an endpoint that returns an array of data to my JSON RPC call made from the store. I'm expecting the grid to show only 30 records initially and then add more as I go on scrolling. I see that the `pageSize` only decides how much AJAX calls to make for the data. Meaning, if my data returned has 100 records, setting the pageSize to 20 makes 5 calls. But, all the 100 records are returned in every call. Besides, my infinite scroll doesn't work. Do I need to handle anything on the server side as well for making only the 30 records required and not all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to interpret the `start` `limit` query parameters on the server side

so on initial call would be `/?start=0&limit=20` so your server will return record 0-20.
if you begin to scroll the next request will be `/?start=20&limit=40` and you will return record 20-40.

also notice the `leadingBufferZone` that is the record count that gets loaded into the non visibly area to allow smooth scrolling.

Comment: Do you set these parameters as: `autoLoad: params{ start: 0, limit: 20 }`. Also, do I need handle these parameters on the server side?

Comment: no ExtJS sets these parameters for you :) and yes you need to handle this on the server side

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would I set these params so that I can receive them on the server end?

Comment: Also, do I need to set autoLoad to true if I want only n number of records?

Comment: Okay. But please can you tell me how do I pass and handle the parameters on the server end?

Comment: as I said: ExtJS will send these parameters automatically, without you doing anything, please inspect the requests in your browser and you will see the query parameters. then you need to pass these parameters to your database query

Comment: How do I access those parameters in my PHP code? I mean what variable?

Comment: $_GET["start"] and $_GET["limit"]

Comment: Aha... please let me try this! I've tried getting the post variables but it turns out blank!

Comment: ExtJS will only send post params if you try to send form-data or create records

Comment: We stopped struggling with infinite scroll and ended up using pagination! Thanks for your help though! :)